How to add custom headers to one of the multiple temporary redirects using playwright in python?
Is there any way to capture/intercept the temporary re-directs using playwright and add custom headers?
I have a page in which the initial request will give response with status code 303 that will redirect to multiple redirects with status code 307 (Temporary redirects). I need to intercept one the temporary redirect and add an header and send the request. Is there any way to handle this?
#HTTPHeaders #PythonPlaywright
I tried using handle_request() to capture the redirects like below:
def handle_request(route, request):
    # Update the headers if match_string is present in url
    if "match_string" in request.url:
        print(f"Modifying headers for redirected request: {request.url}")
        headers = {**request.headers, 'custom_header_1': 'value_!23'}
        route.continue_(headers=headers)
    else:
        # Continue the request without modification
        route.continue_()

But, does not capture the temporary redirects which is initiated from another redirect. So unable to add headers using handle_request.

Can you share a sample page under test, or the actual page as a [mcve]? Without that, it's very difficult to help. Thanks.

Try using route.request
def handle_request(route):
    headers = route.request.headers
    if "match_string" in route.request.url:
        headers['custom_header_1'] = 'value_!23'
    route.continue_(headers=headers)

See also this sample from the official documentation:
https://playwright.dev/python/docs/network#modify-requests
